# Google chrome extension install failure

Tags: google-chrome, extension

i want to install GoogleChrome extension yet whenever i click install it says
Extension Install Failure.

> Invalid value for 'permissions[0]'.

What causes that?

thank you.

Comment: Is it for a specific extension?

Comment: yess. Missing e. extension for tumblr.

Comment: If you try another extension, does it give you the same error?

Comment: hmmm i cant think of any other extensions.. can you give me one? so i could try?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hamgohmiimamjpabgncmklojoibjknon https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpnmofjhdomgfpdjifhbcpegmcakancg - install those two AskUbuntu extensions. (Or try to).

Comment: no error when installing those extensions.. :O what could be the solution?

Comment: I've figured it out. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Can you edit the question to contain more details, such as are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Chrome Development version. To do that, run the following:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable`

However, be warned that this is Google Chrome **unstable**, and that it won't be stable, and that some features might not work. Also, this will remove Google Chrome stable.

*[Via chromium-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5b01e50d60c8ed57?pli=1)*

Comment: `E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

are these fine?

Comment: Means that you have some PPA's that aren't for your system. Just run `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable` - you can ask about fixing your PPA's in another question.

Comment: `E: Couldn't find package google-chrome-unstable`
how bout this?